# How to Retrieve Contact from Google mail by asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been using this code because there is an error:

> Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add("GmailContact");
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("EmailId");
            RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings("GetGmailContact", txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
            rs.AutoPaging = true;
            ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);
            Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
            foreach (Contact t in f.Entries)
            {
                foreach (EMail email in t.Emails)
                {
                    DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
                    row["EmailId"] = email.Address.ToString();
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
            lblStatus.Text = "Total Contact For" + txtUsername.Text + ":" + ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Step
>
> 1 Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project and create project.
>
> 2 Select project, select APIs & auth from top left corner menu.
>
> 3 Select Credentials
>
> 4 Create OAuth with button Create new Client ID (Application type - Installed Aplication.
>
> 5 Fill field Product Name
>
> 6 Save
>
> After that you got Client ID for native application with: Client ID, Client secret, Redirect URIs
>
> Install Google.Apis.Auth from NuGet
>
> Code

```
 string clientId = null; // https://console.developers.google.com/project/xxx
        string clientSecret = null; // https://console.developers.google.com/project/xxx
        string accessCode = null; // You will get this code after GetAccessToken method
        string redirectUri = null; // https://console.developers.google.com/project/xxx
        string applicationName = null; // https://console.developers.google.com/project/xxx
        // Scopes https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en
        string scopes = null; // put your scope like https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/
        string accessType = "offline";
        string tokenType = "refresh";

        OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = scopes,
            AccessType = accessType,
            TokenType = tokenType
        };

        if (accessCode == null)
        {
            string url = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
            // Start webbrowser
            Process.Start(url);

            // Load code from web via popup, etc.
            parameters.AccessCode = accessCodeFromWeb;
        }

        // Check accessToken and refreshToken
        // After first acceess with  GetAccessToken you will get that information
        if (accessToken == null || refreshToken == null)
        {
            OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);

            // Save yours accessToken and refreshToken for next connection
            accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;
            refreshToken = parameters.RefreshToken;
        }
        else
        {
            // Restore your token from config file, etc.
            parameters.AccessToken = accessToken;
            parameters.RefreshToken = refreshToken;
        }

        RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings(applicationName, parameters);

        return new ContactsRequest(rs);
```